# How do i display a list with strings that start with a capital letter at the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit out of my depth here and I'm hoping this is actually possible.

I'd like to be able to call a function that re-arrange my list so that items that begin with capital letter come first

I've been looking through stackoverflow and googling for a while now with nothing. Any thoughts?

for example, var items = [banana, Apple, Mango, pineapple, Melon]

the function should place Apple Mango and Melon to the beginning as they start with capital letters

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :) It would be useful to post the code you've already tried.

Comment: @triptych just wondering if its possible, i wouldnt know where to start

Comment: Is there a hidden requirement in the order that you wrote Apple Mango Melon? Do you want to preserve their order from the source? Maybe, something else? You've defined a partial ordering based only on the case of the first letter.

Answer (score 3):

```
var items = ["banana", "Apple", "Mango", "pineapple", "Melon"]

items.sort();

alert(items)
```

You can see it in action in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbh7gnd0/)

The reason this works is that capital letters come before lower case in the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/).  So when you sort the list it does it based on the ascii values of the strings.

Comment: Please take the time to explain how your code works, what it does, otherwise the OP is unlikely to learn anything.

Comment: JavaScript strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units, not ASCII. Further, the `sort` method works on Unicode codepoints. Try this test case : ["meter", "Ångström"].

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look to just the first character and check if it a lower case letter, then sort it to the end. It does not sort the list by the whole string.

This proposal uses a sort function for [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), which returns a value for sorting. The value indicates the relation between two elements.

```js
var items = ['banana', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'pineapple', 'Melon', 'Apricot'];

items.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a[0] === a[0].toLowerCase()) - (b[0] === b[0].toLowerCase());
});

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that you can customize.

```
startsWithCapitalLetter = function(string) {
    return (string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() === string.charAt(0));
}

var items = ['banana', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'pineapple', 'Melon'];
var upper = [];
var lower = [];

for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
    if (items.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    if (startsWithCapitalLetter(items[i])) {
        upper.push(items[i]);
    } else {
        lower.push(items[i]);
    }
  }
}

var sorted = upper.concat(lower);
console.log(sorted);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzvx2a12/1/

Answer (score -1):

My answer with jquery. You can get the equivalent code from javascript but the logic is there.

HTML:

```
<div class="waka">wa</div>
<div class="waka">we</div>
<div class="waka">wi</div>
<div class="waka">wo</div>
<div class="waka">wu</div>
```

JS:

```
var waka = '';
var weke = '';
var alert = '';
var i = 0;
$(".waka").each(function(){
   waka = $(this).html()[0]; // You get first char from all your data 
   weke = $(this).html()[0].toUpperCase();
    if( waka ==  weke ) {
   alert = alert + 'Data ' + i + ' Is uppercase <br />';
}
  else{
   alert = alert + 'Data ' + i + ' Is not uppercase <br />';
}
i = i+1;

});
$(".alert").html(alert);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/syb886fk/1/

Comment: How is this even supposed to answer the question?